# Return the ID of an element that is found using Xpath C#

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to find the ID of a HTML element that I am searching on by xpath as follows:-

```
var path = string.Format(("(//*[text()='{0}'])"), buttonName);

actualButtonName = (Browser.FindXPath(path, new Options {Match = First}).Id);

return actualButtonName;
```

this currently returns blank for the actualButtonName

This will enable me to find the ID of an element on the page I am looking at and once I have returned the ID I can then use it elsewhere.
Hope you can help

Comment: Please display the html of the button. I think I know the answer but want to see the HTML first to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element attributes with the following code:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path));
var elementId = element.GetAttribute("id");
```